# Get login username in java

Tags: java, authentication

How can I get the username/login name in Java?

This is the code I have tried...

```
try{
    LoginContext lc = new LoginContext(appName,new TextCallbackHandler());
    lc.login();
    Subject subject = lc.getSubject();
    Principal principals[] = (Principal[])subject.getPrincipals().toArray(new Principal[0]);

    for (int i=0; i<principals.length; i++) {
        if (principals[i] instanceof NTUserPrincipal || principals[i] instanceof UnixPrincipal) {
            String loggedInUserName = principals[i].getName();
        }
    }

}
catch(SecurityException se){
    System.out.println("SecurityException: " + se.getMessage());
}
```

I get a `SecurityException` when I try to run this code. Could someone please tell me whether I'm heading in the right direction, and help me to understand the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid to misunderstand you, but I don't understand your question. Which login username? Windows/GNU Linux login? Basic authentication on a webserver?

Comment: It's impossible to understand anything when no details are posted

Answer (score 260, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

Comment: +1 you can print the System.properties to get a lot of informations the VM is initialized with

Comment: For me this prints the name of the user executing the VM. Not the logged in user on the java application.

Comment: Is this defined anywhere in a widely available third party library?  Or is there a constant defined anywhere in JDK provided classes for the `user.name` property name?

Comment: There's no constant field defining the property name, but it is defined in the apidoc of [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29): _"This set of system properties always includes values for the following keys"_.

Answer (score 29):

in Unix:

```
new com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem().getUsername()
```

in Windows:

```
new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName()
```

in Solaris:

```
new com.sun.security.auth.module.SolarisSystem().getUsername()
```

Comment: This code goes against Java's philosophy of write once, run anywhere (introduction of OS specific code), and secondly, it creates a dependency on Sun's implementation of Java.

Comment: Trying to get the username is by definition platform-specific. A JVM running on a single-user system might not have a username at all.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: If there's no username, then the `user.name` property should just be null.  I agree with @JinKim, don't write OS-dependent stuff.

Comment: user.name can be set on the command-line, so it very much depends what the use-case is

Comment: Classes under com.sun packages, should not be used by a developer. They are internal and may change in the future.

Comment: The `com.sun` classes are not accessible by default in Java 9+. This solution will not work for it.

Comment: @Thunderforge com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem still exists in Java17 , UnixSystem and SolarisSystem does not.

Answer (score 17):

inspired by **@newacct**'s answer, a code that can be compiled in any platform:

```
String osName = System.getProperty( "os.name" ).toLowerCase();
String className = null;
String methodName = "getUsername";

if( osName.contains( "windows" ) ){
    className = "com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem";
    methodName = "getName";
}
else if( osName.contains( "linux" ) ){
    className = "com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem";
}
else if( osName.contains( "solaris" ) || osName.contains( "sunos" ) ){
    className = "com.sun.security.auth.module.SolarisSystem";
}

if( className != null ){
    Class<?> c = Class.forName( className );
    Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod( methodName );
    Object o = c.newInstance();
    System.out.println( method.invoke( o ) );
}
```

Comment: Good use of reflection :)

Comment: This will break on Windows since the method on NTSystem to get the username is "getName()" and not "getUsername()". I suppose you can do a further check and then invoke the right method. Bizarre this isn't abstracted into an OS agnostic mechanism by the JRE though?

Comment: The `com.sun` classes are not accessible by default in Java 9+. This solution will not work for it.

Comment: Unless some new API was added, I think the only thing that will work in Java 9 would be [dfa's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797569/531762).

Comment: @Thunderforge Tested it on Java 17, looks like com.sun.security is still there.

Answer (score 16):

System.getProperty("user.name") is not a good security option since that environment variable could be faked:
C:\ set USERNAME="Joe Doe"
java ...
// will give you System.getProperty("user.name") 
You ought to do:

```
com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem NTSystem = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem();
System.out.println(NTSystem.getName());
```

JDK 1.5 and greater.

I use it within an applet, and it has to be signed.
[info source](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0048.html)

Comment: This isn't a complete solution, since it only works under Windows.

Comment: Could this be spoofed too, e.g. with a custom classloader or a custom implementation of `com.sun.security.auth.module.NYSystem` higher in the classpath? I don't know if the Java runtime tries to prevent against such exploits, but I don't think there will be any unfakeable way to make it 'secure' except by running code on a box that is inaccessible to the potentially-malicious client.

Comment: I just successfully managed to replace the implementation of NTSystem.getName() using PowerMock (which I believe uses a custom classloader), so you really can't rely on something like this for 'security'... however I don't know how things are in the applet world. I would have thought that if someone can provide custom system properties then they can also provide custom classes or custom classloaders.

Comment: -1 Because it only works on Windows. You should NOT use this.

Comment: @bacar: I agree, that one shouldn't rely on this and think one is pretty secure. But in my opinion security is about "levels". And it's way easier to change the environment variable than powermocking a method. In a non-IT company using NTSystem rather than the environment variable more than halves the amount of people who are able to pull it off :P. So you get a bit more security, but in turn lose some java conventions on the road.

Comment: If you use "getDomain()" in conjunction with "getName()", it's pretty secure for Windows at least compared to using System.getProperty("user.name");

Answer (score 7):

Using JNA its simple:

```
String username = Advapi32Util.getUserName();
System.out.println(username);

Advapi32Util.Account account = Advapi32Util.getAccountByName(username);
System.out.println(account.accountType);
System.out.println(account.domain);
System.out.println(account.fqn);
System.out.println(account.name);
System.out.println(account.sidString);
```

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

Comment: This doesn't work if you are logged in as a domain user but there is also a local user of the same name. getAccountByName will return information for the local user.

Answer (score 2):

The *'set Username="Username" '* is a temporary override that only exists as long as the cmd windows is still up, once it is killed off, the variable loses value. So i think the

> System.getProperty("user.name");

is still a short and precise code to use.

Answer (score 1):

`System.getenv().get("USERNAME");`
 - works on windows !

In environment properties you have the information you need about computer and host! I am saying again! Works on WINDOWS !

Comment: What about `System.getenv("username")` ? :)

Comment: Doens' work if the VM - say tomcat - is started as a windows service, it returns something which includes the host name

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution for WINDOWS ONLY

In cases where the application (like Tomcat) is started as a windows service, the System.getProperty("user.name") or System.getenv().get("USERNAME") return the user who started the service and not the current logged in user name.

Also in Java 9 the NTSystem etc classes will not be accessible

So workaround for windows: You can use *wmic*, so you have to run the below command

```
wmic ComputerSystem get UserName
```

If available, this will return output of the form:

```
UserName
{domain}\{logged-in-user-name}
```

Note: For windows you need to use cmd /c as a prefix, so below is a crude program as an example:

```
    Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c wmic ComputerSystem get UserName".split(" "));
    System.out.println(exec.waitFor());
    try (BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(exec.getInputStream()))) {
        System.out.println(bw.readLine() + "\n" + bw.readLine()+ "\n" + bw.readLine());
    }
```

Comment: com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem still exists in Java17 .. however, UnixSystem and SolarisSystem are not.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in linux centos

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();   
for (String envName : env.keySet()) { 
 System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName)); 
}

System.out.println(env.get("USERNAME"));
```