# How to find the name of the user in the OS using java

Tags: java, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get login username in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797549/get-login-username-in-java)

I am looking for a way to find you the name of the user in the OS in java so I can get the right directory on how to find out whether a there is a missing file on the user's appdata.
I am using this code:

`File myFile = new File("C:" + File.separator + "Users" + File.separator, "Matty" + File.separator, "AppData" + File.separator, "Roaming");

System.out.println(myFile.isDirectory());

if (myFile.isDirectory() = true)

{
//This will install the program, but i need to find out whether it is already installed

installer.install()

}`

There must be a code for this as most installers have to know what the user's name is!

Comment: Wouldn't such code be OS-specific?

Comment: You mean i would have to use a batch file?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public class OSName
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Your username is: " + System.getProperty("user.name"));
    }
}
```

The relevant docs are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: How could I make that a variable?

Comment: @Matthew - Look at the docs. `System.getProperty(String key)` returns a `String`.

Comment: The name of the system property with the user's home directory is "user.home". For an overview of the Java system properties see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html.