# How to execute a .jar file inside project directory in Java?

Tags: java

I have a .jar file that I want to execute in java. The .jar file is located inside the main project directory. How can I do that

```
public void pickColor (ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String filePath = "pickColor.jar";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" java -jar " + filePath);
}
```

If I add the full path of the file it works ...

Comment: How about creating a new Thread for executing It?

Comment: you need to use absolute path to fix this issue

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693540/how-to-run-a-jar-file-from-within-java-program

Comment: Please refer the previous answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936266/execute-jar-file-from-a-java-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the below code

```
public void pickColor (ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   String fileName = "pickColor.jar";
   String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" java -jar " + filePath + "\" + fileName);
}
```

Comment: It's a very good ideea but I need something like filePath+"\\src\\sample"

Comment: I am not getting you. you mean you want file path till class path?

Comment: Yeah! But it's all right , I've moved the jar file to the main project directory

Answer (score 0):

The most realiable alternative I think is to write the jar to temp file. Some thing like:

```
    File file = File.createTempFile("pickColor", ".jar");
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(getClass().getResource(filePath), file);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" java -jar " + filePath);
```

`FileUtils` is from apache common-io.