# Calling Active-x object from Javascript inside Java code

Tags: java, javascript, liferay, activexobject

I'm trying to get windows username from liferay portlet in java code using javascript and active-x.
When I run the code only with javascript and acitive-x on plain HTML it works.
But when I put it in java, it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
String script = "function getUser() {return ((new ActiveXObject('WScript.NetWork')).UserName); }";  
try {
    engine.eval(script);
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}  

Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;  

try {
    log.info("try invoke script");
    String teste = (String) inv.invokeFunction("getUser");
    log.info("meu teste " +teste);
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I change the content on function for somthing else like returning string it prints the result.

Comment: S3iB, does it returns the user who are acessing the page or the user loggen on the server?

Comment: S3iB, your answer doesn't solve my problem. I want the user who a acessing the page rather than user who a logged in to server wich is always same!

Answer (score 2):

Java-s JavaScript doesn't have Active X capabilities, but you don't have to use JavaScript to get the running machines users username.
[Get login username in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797549/get-login-username-in-java)

If you want to know client-s OS-s username then one approach would be to use client side JavaScript to find it out and submit this information to server side via AJAX.