# How to get login information of currently logged on user on client's windows machine using java?

Tags: java, web, windows-authentication

I need to authenticate my application users using Windows Authentication. As far as i know we can do it Configuring IIS server and ASP page simply. But in java based application where server is Websphere it's not so direct. Using SPENGO and other third party extensions of LDAP, I can query Active Directory. But the question is how to fetch user's credentials using which Active Directory will be searched.
One solution is, give user a login screen and ask him to enter his Windows credentials. If we use this solution, what's the point of having windows authentication?
Hence, I am looking for a way to pass user's windows logon information to server using which, java will query Active Directory.
I have tried using javascript's ActiveXObject. It Pops up stating security issue in IE 9.
I have tried using java's request.getRemoteUser() method. It returns null.
Looking forward for help.

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797549/get-login-username-in-java

Comment: @Cerberus: this is to retrun username on local machine. I need to find username of client machine.