# Finding current username with scala

Tags: scala

I wish to find the current username in scala.

On the command line I can do:

```
whoami
```

In python, I can do:

```
import getpass
user_name = getpass.getuser()
```

How do I find the username in Scala?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the Java API for this:

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

See more (Java) options here: [Get login username in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797549/get-login-username-in-java)

Comment: There is now also `scala.util.Properties.userName`, which may not have existed at the time of this answer.